# How to display the class for the active menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, drupal-8

Here is the `menu.twig.html` template provided by Drupal Bootstrap :

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - classes: A list of classes to apply to the top level <ul> element.
 * - dropdown_classes: A list of classes to apply to the dropdown <ul> element.
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 *
 * Define a custom macro that will render all menu trees.
 */
#}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, classes, dropdown_classes) %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul{{ attributes.addClass(menu_level == 0 ? classes : dropdown_classes) }}>
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set item_classes = item.url.getOption('container_attributes').class | split(" ")
      %}
      {%
        set item_classes = [
          item.is_expanded and item.below ? 'expanded dropdown',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active active-trail',
          loop.first ? 'first',
          loop.last ? 'last',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
        {% set link_title = item.title %}
        {% set link_attributes = item.link_attributes %}
        {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded and item.below %}
          {% set link_title %}{{ link_title }} <span class="caret"></span>{% endset %}
          {% set link_attributes = link_attributes.addClass('dropdown-toggle').setAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown') %}
        {% endif %}
        {# Must use link() here so it triggers hook_link_alter(). #}
        {{ link(link_title, item.url, link_attributes.addClass(item.in_active_trail ? 'active-trail')) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ _self.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass(classes), menu_level + 1, classes, dropdown_classes) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{#
  Invoke the custom macro defined above. If classes were provided, use them.
  This allows the template to be extended without having to also duplicate the
  code above. @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ _self.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, classes ?: ['menu', 'menu--' ~ menu_name|clean_class, 'nav'], dropdown_classes ?: ['dropdown-menu']) }}
```

Here is the main menu HTML code :

```
<ul class="menu menu--main nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="/banque" data-drupal-link-system-path="banque">Banques</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cashback" data-drupal-link-system-path="cashback">Cashback</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active active-trail">
    <a href="/avis" class="active-trail is-active" data-drupal-link-system-path="avis">Avis</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/essentiel" data-drupal-link-system-path="essentiel">Essentiel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="/actu" data-drupal-link-system-path="actu">Actu</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to customize this menu and add an icon before each menu link and the number of page elements in a badge.

Here is the custom code I want for my main menu :

```
<ul class="menu menu--main nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="/banque" data-drupal-link-system-path="banque"><i class="fas fa-piggy-bank fa-lg"></i> Banques <span class="badge badge-light">{{ drupal_view_result('accueil_banque', 'page_1')|length }}</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cashback" data-drupal-link-system-path="cashback"><i class="fas fa-undo fa-lg"></i> Cashback <span class="badge badge-light">{{ drupal_view_result('accueil_cashback', 'page_1')|length }}</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/avis" data-drupal-link-system-path="avis"><i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Avis <span class="badge badge-light">{{ drupal_view_result('accueil_avis', 'page_1')|length }}</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/essentiel" data-drupal-link-system-path="essentiel"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></i> Essentiel <span class="badge badge-light">{{ drupal_view_result('accueil_essentiel', 'page_1')|length }}</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/actu" data-drupal-link-system-path="actu"><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-lg"></i> Actu <span class="badge badge-light">{{ drupal_view_result('accueil_actu', 'page_1')|length }}</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when I click on a menu link, the menu is not displayed as active.

How can I have the same behavior in my custom code ? With the active class automatically added to the menu link that is currently displayed.

How else can I integrate my custom code into one of the `menu.html.twig` or `menu--main.html.twig` templates ?

In Bootstrap there is a `menu--main.html.twig` template that I copy to my sub-theme, but I don't know how to use it. Here are its contents :

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - classes: A list of classes to apply to the top level <ul> element.
 * - dropdown_classes: A list of classes to apply to the dropdown <ul> element.
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 */
#}
{% extends "menu.html.twig" %}
{%
  set classes = [
    'menu',
    'menu--' ~ menu_name|clean_class,
    'nav',
    'navbar-nav',
  ]
%}
```

Example of the main menu by default with an open link (it is active because the page is displayed) :

[image]

Example of the main menu personalized with an open link (it is not active, because the classes are not automatically added by the template menu.twig.html) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer they gave you in the referenced issue is a very clear one RTFM (Read the f***ing manual) especially the following:

- core/themes/stable/templates/menu.html.twig
- core/themes/classy/templates/menu.html.twig contains {% extends "menu.html.twig" %} (to add a specific class) and expects Stable's menu.html.twig to be extended
- core/themes/YOUR_DIR/templates/menu.html.twig contains {% extends "menu.html.twig" %} (to override a Twig block) and expects Classy's menu.html.twig to be extended — or, really, any of its ancestor themes, because it couldn't care less if Classy's menu.html.twig was removed

Notes:
in point 3, we specifically do NOT want to specify {% extends "@classy/menu.html.twig" %} because we don't want to care. We just want the parent theme's template — according to the theme registry — to be extended.
    in point 1, the "root template" could just as well not live in a theme, but in a module. That's also a valid use case.

So you have an issue because you state `menu.twig.html` but your module `extends "menu.html.twig"` so make sure your naming is right.

[The Drupal handbook](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/) statesNEVER to fiddle around with the delivered templates, rather extend it with user specific modulues.

> Q: Where should I make changes?
>
> A: In a custom sub-theme
>
> You should never modify any theme or sub-theme that is packaged and
>   released from Drupal.org. If you do, all changes you have made would
>   be lost once that theme is updated. This makes keeping track of
>   changes next to impossible.
>
> Instead, you should create a custom sub-theme that isn't hosted on
>   Drupal.org.

Comment: I have this answer but I have no solution https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3125781#comment-13543452 The class of your answer should be added automatically